# Laravel leftJoin now showing results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm newbie on laravel and lerning leftJoin.

I have table called "**users**" with row "**steam_id**".

I have another table called "**matches"**. "**matches**" table have a unique row called 
"**match_id**".

Last one table called "**match_players**" have row called "match_id" aswell and "**steam_id**. 
"match_id" same as table row "matches -> match_id".

I need take out info by using user steam_id by match_id from matches.

Controller:

```
 $user->LatestMatches = DB::table('match_players AS mp')
->leftJoin('matches AS ma', 'ma.match_id', '=', 'mp.match_id')
->where('mp.steam_id', '=', $user->steam_id)
->where('team', '=', 2)
->where('team', '=', 1)
->select("mp.*", "ma.map")
->get('');
```

Blade:

```
@foreach ($user->LatestMatches as $lastmatch)
{{ $lastmatch->map }}
@endforeach
```

But dont getting any info. Sorry if u don`t understand what i need todo. Thanks for replies and helping me understanding laravel!

Comment: `where team =1 and where team=2` cannot be true at same time for a single row

Comment: So how can i take TEAM 1 and TEAM 2 results?

Comment: Use `whereIn('team', [1, 2])`.

Answer (score 1):

`->where('team', '=', 1)->where('team', '=', 2)` doesn't work because it selects players who are in `team 1` *AND* `team 2` at the same time. No player can fulfill this constraint.

Use `->whereIn('team', [1, 2])` instead. This selects players who are in `team 1` *OR* `team 2`.